Issue with spl-associated-token-account Version Conflict in anchor-spl v0.30.1
I'm working on a Solana program using Anchor, and I’ve encountered a version conflict when running cargo update with anchor-spl v0.30.1. The issue arises from the dependency on spl-associated-token-account = "^3", but the latest version available on crates.io is 1.0.3.
Here is the error I’m seeing:
vbnet
Copy code
error: failed to select a version for the requirement spl-associated-token-account = "^3"
candidate versions found which didn't match: 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1
location searched: crates.io index
required by package anchor-spl v0.30.1
I’ve checked my Cargo.toml, and I’m only importing anchor-spl as suggested, without any direct reference to spl-associated-token-account. I've also tried removing any patches or overrides, and the problem still persists.
Steps I’ve taken:
Verified my Cargo.toml to ensure there’s no direct import of spl-associated-token-account.
Tried downgrading to anchor-spl v0.29.0, which still caused a similar issue but with a lower version requirement for spl-associated-token-account = "^2.2".
Removed any patches or overrides that may have been conflicting.
Additional Information:
Rust version: rustc 1.80.1
Anchor version: 0.30.1
Cargo version: 1.80.0
Solana version: 1.18.0
Has anyone else faced this issue with anchor-spl v0.30.1? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Could you try solana version 1.18.22? There are some program examples here which use anchor-spl and they seem to work fine: https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/97505283f8a8bb2b6cd17914425abc9634868764/tokens/nft-operations/anchor/Cargo.lock

You might want to start with a working example like https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/tests/spl/token-wrapper and then modify it for your needs, since the build should work. There's likely some other dependency in your tree that's requiring the earlier version of SPL associated token account
